# Call server method without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I was reading a lot articles and posts about this but I couldn't faint solution for my problem.

I have some method in aspx.cs page. Method doesn't return anything, it just change value in labels, text boxes,...

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void MethodName()
{
   //some code
}
```

On frontend I have radio button which should call this method. It work when I call regular server side method (rdbMethodName_CheckedChanged) which reload page. Now I'd like to call this method without reload. I tried usin Ajax

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbTwoSub" runat="server" GroupName="Subscription" value="2" AutoPostBack="false" OnCheckedChanged="rdbMethodName_CheckedChanged" />
```

To call ajax method I set AutoPostBack to false and create js for call it

```
$("#ctl00_PageContent_rbTwoSub").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "buy_sql_tools_new.aspx/MethodName?Product=ProductName",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Success: ', data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                }
            });
        });
```

This code return in console console html code for page without paramenter and without calling this method.

I need just to call backend method which going to change all values and that's it. Does anyone have some idea how to do this.

Only one thing more I have on mind and that is to rewrite all C# code to javascript code and to call only js methods on clicks

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-* Edit 12/16/2015

Hi, I tried to call simple ajax post which will return me single value but it also don't work

here is code below

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "buy_sql_tools_new.aspx/HelloWorld",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    console.log('error' + msg);
                }
            });
```

aspx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello";
}
```

Comment: you will have to do sth like an AJAX call to server and obtain new values and then use a client-side template engine (e.g handlebars, or other like [Tao](https://github.com/foo123/Tao.js) author) to render these in the browser without refreshing the page

Comment: you still have `OnCheckedChanged` in the markup - you'll need to add a click event listener to the control as RadioButton does not have an OnClientClick property

Comment: @NikosM. tnx, I going to try this tomorrow.

Comment: @JaromandaX there is no problem with click event, it work. There is problem with ajax and passing values/changes

Comment: Sorry, I re-read the code, and I see that it's on change event you've tied to the control - however, the `OnCheckedChanged` event is still firing - have you tried removing that?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I tried to remove it but it still don't work. I've just sow explanation that I cant call method on way as I thought (see post and comments below)

Answer (score 2):

Your webmethod should be static. Also if you want to actually change something on the success of the ajax call you will have to return the data that you will be updating.

Try doing something like this. Note the example is using [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for serialization.

jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 

        $("input:radio[name='Subscription']").click(function () {

            var selectedRadio = $("input:radio[name='Subscription']:checked").val();

            //Code to fetch complex datatype
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "buy_sql_tools_new.aspx/GetProduct?product=ProductName",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{ id :'" + selectedRadio + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                  //perform the desired operations here eg. change labels and etc by getting the values from data object.
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });

        });            
    });
</script>
```

WebMethod in the codebehind:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string GetProduct(string product)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Get the product
            Product product = new Product();
            product.Name = "Sql tool";
            product.Price = 3.99M;
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
            //example output
            //{
            //  "Name": "Apple",
            //  "Price": 3.99,
            //}
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             result = ex.ToString();
            //Exception Handling Logic goes here
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Tnx for answer. I always used Ajax and Json like in your exam above (in MVC) but now I work with web.form and I'd like to not manage Json post. I just try to set values in server side method ( someID.Text("sometext") ). Can i do this or i should pass Json back and then change values

Comment: you can't change the page from its code-behind. this is because the method is static. because it's static the method belongs to every instance of the page. if more than one person has the page open, the method would not know which page to update. so you must send the info back to the ajax call.

Comment: @wazz Tnx for explanation .

Comment: @Agop Dogramadzhiyan I tried yours code but i got error. I copied your methods and ajax call but it was not success.

Comment: @Agop Dogramadzhiyan I just debug application and in error response I got whole page html