# Why code behind method should be static if calling from ajax and web service (asmx) method not static?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asmx

I have come across a situation where i have to call an asp page code-behind method using ajax from client side. I found that code behind method should be static in order to call from client side using ajax where as ASMX web service method is normal class method.

Why code-behind method should be static and why ASMX web service method is not?
is there any object theory is running behind the scene or any other theory?

Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can find answer on your question [right here](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/)

> **So, why do page method calls have to be static?**
>
> If you’re implementing page methods, you’re probably well aware of their excellent performance. They are especially performant compared to the
> UpdatePanel’s partial postbacks.
>
> They are efficient largely because
> they do not require the ViewState to be POSTed and they do not create
> an instance of the Page, while partial postbacks do both of these
> things. As we now know, a page method couldn’t create an instance of
> the page even if desired, since the ViewState isn’t provided in the
> request.
>
> **This is exactly why they must be marked as static**.
>
> They cannot interact with the instance properties and methods of your Page
> class, because a page method call creates no instance of the Page or
> any of its controls. Page methods are roughly equivalent to shorthand
> for standalone web services. In fact, the ScriptManager even calls
> them exactly as it would a regular web service.

Comment: thanks for your information about Page-Methods. But actually i am using ajax call for calling code-behind web methods.

Answer (score 1):

The methods that you are calling via AJAX are called [`Page methods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) because they belong to the [`System.Web.UI.Page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  If you read up on the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), you'll see that the `Page` class is instantiated during the lifecycle and once it does its job all of the data it needs to be re-instantated is serialized in the ViewState.  On postback, this data is sent back to the server through a hidden `input` field and used to create another instance of the `Page` class.

The `Page` class can't be instantiated from your code behind because the methods you define in your code behind belong to the `Page` class.  This is why these methods have to be defined as `static`, because static methods do no require an instance of their class in order to be invoked.  You can almost think of them as primitive web service.

Methods of a web service like an ASMX service do not have to be static because they are not confined by this restriction.  They can be instantiated by the processes in their own applications.

Answer (score 0):

from: [Call server method without refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240187/call-server-method-without-refresh-page/34242311?noredirect=1#comment56351302_34242311):

you can't change the page from its code-behind. this is because the method is static. because it's static *the method belongs to every instance of the page*. if more than one person has the page open, *the method would not know which page to update*. so you must send the info back to the ajax call.

also: http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/